# Open a file with Notepad in C#

Tags: c#, file

How I open a file in c#?  I don't mean reading it by textreader and readline().  I mean open it as an independent file in notepad.

Comment: You want to launch an instance of notepad from your program and have it open a specific file?

Comment: Note: At when I tried it with .Net 2.0, `Process.Start` did not automatically expand "%windir%", though omiting it as in [viabhav's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c/4055295#4055295) or expanding it explicitly (`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")`) worked successfully.

Comment: You can integrate a notepad clone into your application and customize it to function just the way you want it. I write a notepad clone in C# you can find it here: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2012/04/notepad-clone-in-net-winforms.html

Answer (score 237):

You need `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`.

The simplest example:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);
```

More Generic Approach:

```
Process.Start(fileName);
```

The second approach is probably a better practice as this will cause the windows Shell to open up your file with it's associated editor. Additionally, if the file specified does not have an association, it'll use the `Open With...` dialog from windows.

**Note to those in the comments, thankyou for your input. My quick n' dirty answer was slightly off, i've updated the answer to reflect the correct way.**

Comment: I would do some escaping if I were you.

Comment: I agree that this is one way to do this, another way if you wanted to open the document but not run the program would be to use something along the lines of:   richTextBox1.LoadFile(Program.editInC,RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText) for loading the actual contents into a file.

Comment: It's better to pass the file name as a second parameter. Actually, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx), your code shouldn't work, as the single parameter of `Process.Start` is document or application file name, whereas yours is the application name combined with the command line parameter.

Comment: @Albin: Thanks, totally overlooked that one :p @Jim: I believe the question was asking how to launch an editor. @Vlad: Thanks, you are correct.

Comment: Using `Process.Start(filename)` is a potential command injection, whereby an attacker could substitute `MyTextFile.txt` for `MyMalicious.bat` or `fdisk ...`. Better to use `Process.Start("notepad.exe", filename)`.

Answer (score 35):

You are not providing a lot of information,
but assuming you want to open just any file on your computer
with the application that is specified for the default handler for that filetype,
you can use something like this:

```
var fileToOpen = "SomeFilePathHere";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = fileToOpen
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The UseShellExecute parameter tells Windows to use the default program for the type of file you are opening.

The WaitForExit will cause your application to wait until the application you luanched has been closed.

Comment: And, in addition, it would be good to use a `if(File.Exists(fileToOpen))` to avoid running into an exception.

Answer (score 26):

this will open the file with the default windows program (notepad if you haven't changed it);

```
Process.Start(@"c:\myfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 16):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "notepad.exe", "text.txt");
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), calling `notepad.exe` with the file as a parameter.

```
 Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", pathToFile);
```

Comment: By the way, %pathVariables% do not work with this method. `Process.Start(@"%windir%\notepad.exe");` throws a Win32Exception:"Cannot find file" but normally it should work.

Comment: @Aren: which can be solved calling Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()

Answer (score 8):

Use [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to launch an instance of Notepad.exe.