# Open a file not using default program

Tags: c#, file-type

How in c# can I make a file open with a specified program ie: not the default program for that file type

Comment: Take look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `System.Diagnostics.Process(String, String)` method that you can find further documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Sample:

```
// Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
```

For future posts, I suggest you post code that you have already attempted/written to help us better help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you can build a command-line to run the program (including passing the input file as a command-line parameter) than build the command line ans use `Process.Start`.

Of course this assumes

1. you know the path to the program's executable
2. you know how to pass the filename as a command-line parameter.

How 2. works depends on the program.  It could be as simple as

```
Process.Start("MyProgram.exe","MyFile.dat")
```

But other programs may require a command-line switch or other information.

Comment: 1) is a yes  2) i do not, could you give a example?

Comment: 2) depends on the program.  Read it's docs or search for the program name in the registry to get the start options.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers I found on the internet say that you can just use `Process.Start("MyProgram.exe")`

but I always get an exception that the file is not found so I got it working by specifying the full path to the .exe file in the installation folder

`Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")`

you can find the installation folder by clicking on the right mouse button on a shortcut in the desktop and press `Open file location`.

[image: right click menu on icon]

[image: windows explorer with chrome.exe highlighted]