# How can I view text file in notepad on button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
private void viewLogFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
     string logger_file = @"\logger.txt";
     string LoggerFileName = Path.Combine(path_log, logger_file);    
}
```

I want when I click the menu item it will open the LoggerFileName automatic in notepad and show me the notepad window .

Comment: who down voted the OP please leave some comment?

Comment: I don't like the number `3`, so +1 for you to make it `2` and hope no one will down vote you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if txt file default open application set as notepad you can open it as below

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(LoggerFileName);
```

below will open notepad with given file

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", LoggerFileName);
```

**Note :**

```
string LoggerFileName = Path.Combine(
                      Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath), 
                     "log", 
                     "logger.txt");
```

Comment: So basically rip the answers out of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: the first usually opens file with notepad but in some case if txt file is opened by another application as default, that application will show the file content.

Comment: `"notepad"` can also work as well as `"notepad.exe"` :), just some helpful comment for others. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you even researched this at all?

```
private void viewLogFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log\";
            string logger_file = @"\logger.txt";
            string LoggerFileName = Path.Combine(path_log, logger_file);
            Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, @"\notepad.exe"), LoggerFileName);
        }
```

All you needed to google was really "get notepad path c#" and "start process c#".

Comment: This opens file with notepad.

Comment: @KingKing I'm pretty sure that's what he asked for.

Comment: Ok i tried but for some reason LoggerFileName contain only "\\logger.txt" why is that ? Therefore it cant find the file .

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance along with auto foreground window and a button.

Comment: yes, I've just made a statement :)

Comment: @joneK Give me the value of `MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log");`

Comment: The Path_Log contain : "C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\ScreenVideoRecorder\\ScreenVideoRecorder\\log" and i see on my hard disk this directory and the log file inside

Comment: @joneK Slight bug with your string, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Process class in the .Net framework.

Use it with [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) set to true. Then you can "start" the .txt file, and the user could've chosen it's favorite editor. The default, however, would be NotePad anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
   private void viewLogFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        string path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
        string logger_file = @"\logger.txt";
        string LoggerFileName = Path.Combine(path_log, logger_file);
        string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),"notepad.exe")
        Process.Start(notepadPath,LoggerFileName);
    }
```

?

Comment: What if the System root folder is `D:\\` or any other than `C:\\`?

Comment: good point. I edited my answer.