# Open a text file in C# programmatically

Tags: text, operating-system, command, code-injection, process.start

I want to open a text file programmatically using C#. I have used :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test.txt);
```

but this code is causing OS command injection problem when scanning for threats.

Is there any way that i can open a text file programmatically?? or way to bypass that OS command injection?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should call a program, say notepad:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);
```

the argument is the file name:

```
 Process.Start("notepad.exe", "Test.txt");
```

See the problem with your code in the comments of this post:
[Open a file with Notepad in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I am trying this solution now and will sumit a scan. Thanks for the immediate reply.

Comment: This doesnot solve the issue, it is still catching the process.start as OS COMMAND INJECTION.

Comment: Are you actually putting in a string such as "this_is_hard_coded.txt" or just passing an argument without any validation? see : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Injection

Comment: First time :
var test = "test.txt"
process.start(test)
I had even validated the variable to check if there it contain 'txt'

Comment: yes , but have you tried passing notepad.exe and test.txt both as hard coded strings (not from args) - if this doesn't work for you I have to give up :)

Comment: yes i have tried this process.start("notepad.exe","test.txt")
- The scan is still pointing this as a threat

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 string _path = "c:/filepath";
 startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C start {0}", _path);
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```