# Open File and Show Contents

Tags: c#

I am using a streamwriter to write a file. Something like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"path\filename.txt", false))
{}
```

I am already writing to the file. What I want to do now is to open the text file automatically in Windows so that the user can actually see the contents of the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just double-click on the file in Windows to see the contents. What does “open the text file automatically” mean?

Comment: Look at File and FileInfo classes.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Have it open from code instead of double-clicking on the file

Comment: After closing the file, you could [launch Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Use Process.Start(@"path\filename.txt");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant, use [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start(@"path\filename.txt");
```

This will open the text file in the default text file application.